# yii layout no visible changes

Tags: php, layout, yii

I tried force refresh on my browser and change the name of the layout from `main.php` to `main_.php` still nothing happened. No visible effect, no error, no nothing.

I'm sure missing a small detail here. Can anyone guide a beginner in this problem?

Version: Yii 1.1.10

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/

Comment: @PedroL. thanks for the link but i've seen that already and pretty much understand the flow. The header is only found on my `main.php` which should eliminate any duplicate or confusion with how the page is displayed. So I think it is given already that when I modify the `main.php` layout it should be seen on all the pages I have created.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Ur assumptions seem to be valid. So if you still do not see the changes made to your main.php layout it might be some trivial mistake like having changed the default layout (so main.php is not rendered any more)

Comment: Where did you change the name of the layout? In which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the main layout in site/layouts and in themes/layouts too, definitely there are more version of it.

For you the [yii debug toolbar](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar) 3rd party extension would definitely help to identify the layout file that is used, install it.

You can control which layout files is included with the controller's `$layout` property

You need to tell your controller to use layouts from the current module, with single slash notation eg : $layout = '/site/myview' read more about this at: [getLayoutFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getLayoutFile-detail)()

Comment: I think you hit the spot there @Pentium10 ! I got a theme layout which overrides the layout in the views directory. Thank you as well for the `yii debug toolbar` that would help for further development. 

While we're at it how do I make sure that the theme layout does not override the default layout?